# Is bigbluebutton supported html5 in Docker or no?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, devops, bigbluebutton

Sorry if my question will be not correct. But is very important for me.
In last week I tryed to deploy bigbluebutton on virtual server. I know need to use Ubuntu 16.04. But i haved a many misstake with packages (debconf, debconf-18n and etc.) and repositroy.
And I tryed to use a Docker and it was a good idea :))). But bigbluebutton uses adobe flash and in future will be end support. I know bigbluebutton  supported html5.  But i don't understand is a bbb have a html5 version in a docker ?  Maybe someone have a Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/bigbluebutton/docker/, they mention to support both flash and html5.